# How to intercept a keypress?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iOS app, and I want to intercept the key which has been pressed and send the character to another part of the program, as well or instead of to the associated text field. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The delegate method [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a) lets you do what ever you like before the value is added to the text of the text field. You can even decide not to set it on the text field or set some completely different text.